# CSS and gsap JavaScript doesn't work in my file

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to implement a gsap example from [codepen](https://codepen.io/designcourse/pen/bGGmvOe).
Nothing shows when I launch my html file. I remove the styles CSS at the bottom and it started showing. I believe the CSS is scss, which makes it more confusing because I assumed I could use it. The html file is below. I haven't used scss before so it seems strange to me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Home - Brand</title>
    <script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/gsap-latest-beta.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/CSSRulePlugin3.min.js"/>
   </head>
   <body>
<main>
    <div class="content">
        <h1 class="anim1"><span>Bridging the gap</span> <span>between dream</span> <span>and reality</span></h1>
        <p class="anim1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio at ipsa alias modi natus excepturi?</p>
        <a href="#" class="anim1" id="cta">Start Dreaming</a>
    </div>
</main>
<aside>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <img class="swirl" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2621168/swirl.png" alt="Swirl Graphic">
        </div>
</aside>
<script type="text/javascript">
                // 1
                // gsap.from(".content", {duration:1, y:-50, opacity: 0});

                // 1.1   Show Easings  "steps(5)"   "Power2.easeInOut"  "elastic(1, 0.3)"  https://greensock.com/docs/v2/Easing
                // gsap.from(".content", {duration:1, y:-50, opacity: 0, ease: "elastic(1, 0.3)"}); 

                // 2  ADD
                // gsap.from("img", {duration: 1, y: 30, opacity: 0});
                // gsap.from("aside", {duration: 1, opacity: 0, backgroundPosition: '200px 0px'});

                // 3 Show Delay
                // gsap.from("img", {duration: 1, delay: 1.4, y: 30, opacity: 0});
                // gsap.from("aside", {duration: 1, delay: 1.1, opacity: 0, backgroundPosition: '200px 0px'});

                // 4 Show Stagger (add class)
                // gsap.from(".anim1", {duration:1, y:-50, opacity: 0, stagger: .6});

                // 5 Show text reveal animation (add css span:after)
                // <script src="CSSRulePlugin.min.js">

                var rule = CSSRulePlugin.getRule("span:after");
                
                // 6 Show Timeline
                var tl = gsap.timeline({defaults:{duration: 1}});
                tl.from(".anim1", {y:-50, stagger: .6, opacity: 0})
                  .to(rule, {duration: 1.8,cssRule: {scaleY: 0}}, "-=2.2")
                  .from("aside", {backgroundPosition: '200px 0px', opacity: 0}, "-=1.5")
                  .from("img", {y:30, opacity: 0}, "-=.5")

                // 7 Show Click reverse
                document.getElementById('cta').addEventListener('click', () => {
                    console.log('click')
                    tl.reversed() ? tl.play() : tl.reverse();
                })
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 30%;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.line {
    position: absolute;
}

main {
    margin-left: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;

    .content {
        width: 70%;

        h1 {
            font-size: 3em;
            position: relative;

            span {
                display: block;
            }

        }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try to make a css file and connect it to the html file ?

Comment: Yes. Nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code in `<style>` tag uses nesting which is supported by scss.

So to run the above code follow these steps

**Step 1:** Install Sass

```
npm install -g sass
```

**Step 2:** Create a new file as `styles.scss`

**Step 3:** Copy the code from `<style>` tag to `styles.scss` file

**Step 4:** Run the following command in the terminal

```
sass --watch styles.scss:styles.css
```

It will generate new `styles.css` file

**Step 5:** Link this `styles.css` file to the html

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

That's it!